# Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dbal

I am learning Laravel 5 and ran into an error when renaming a column in a table.

```
Created a migration:
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn('age', 'agee');
        });
    }
```

I send a command for migration and I get an error:

```
In MySqlConnection.php line 65:

  Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found
```

Tried reinstalling in this way:

1. deleted record "doctrine/dbal": "^3.1", from composer.json file
2. typed in the console: *composer update*
3. typed in the console: *composer require doctrine/dbal*

The package was reinstalled, but the error persisted. How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem because your doctirne/dbal: v3 , try to downgrade to v2 ,
like this :- doctrine/dbal": "^2.12"
this issue related with your problem :- https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/4439

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped me. Now everything works as it should.

Comment: welcome , dont forget to upvote the answer